# Login is broken

Tags: updates, login

instead of trying to find the answer to why I can't log in, whether it be because of lightdm or Xauthority, I am just trying to update from 14.04 to 14.10. When I try to update it fails. Any help would be amazing.

When I do "do-release-upgrade" it goes through until it asks permission to commence with upgrade, at some point though it says aborting due to network connection. I am connected to the internet though.

Now as I cannot fix the original problem, nor can I upgrade, I decided to try to just clean install using "sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a" it started off working alright up until it came to the files /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config it said not found for 15 different cases that it could not find said files.

Comment: How does it fail? Are there error messages? I recommend expanding your question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the issue where I was unable to upgrade from one version to another. I got stuck in the same place as you. I read all the google's and ended up performing a number of things such as turning of the firewall, connecting to the internet via the cable rather than wireless and such like. All of which just took time and didn't help in the end.

What I did was installed the latest version on a usb flash pen, backed up all my data, made a list of all the apps that I used and then did a fresh install. This I found far better than spending time to try and upgrade the existing one. However, with 15.04 just around the cornet you may want to hold off until it is out.